# woocommerce cart coupon price without tax to display

Tags: woocommerce, cart, coupon, tax

I want woocommerce to display price in cart without tax, reduced by using a coupon.

I want to have:

- price without tax
- coupon value
- price without tax reduced by coupon
- tax
- price with tax

Can anybody help me please?

I was trying to play wit this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','new_customers_discount', 10, 1 );
function new_customers_discount( $wc_cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') ) // We exit

// Only for logged in users
if ($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons)  // We exit

// Only for new customers without orders
if ( wc_get_customer_order_count( get_current_user_id() ) != 10000 ) return;  // We exit


// Calculation
$discount = $wc_cart->cart_contents_total - $coupon ;

$wc_cart->add_fee( __( 'Netto po rabacie', 'woocommerce')."", $discount);
echo '<div id="product-meta"><span class="detaliczna"><p class="item-description"  style="text-align:center; font-size: 14px; display: none; ">' . $wc_cart->add_fee( __( 'TEST', 'woocommerce')."", -$discount ) . ' zł netto</p></span></div>';
```

but no luck. I am not a programmer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it, but i want to change the order. I want to move the nett price on top of VAT

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total', 'bbloomer_wc_discount_total_30', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'bbloomer_wc_discount_total_30', 10, 1 ); 
function bbloomer_wc_discount_total_30() {


global $woocommerce;

$discount_total = 0;

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {

$_product = $values['data'];

    if ( $_product->get_regular_price() ) {
    $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price = $_product->get_sale_price();
    $discount = ($regular_price - $coupon) ;
    $discount_total += $discount;
    }

}

if ( $discount_total > 0 ) {
echo '<tr class="cart-discount">
<th>'. __( 'Razem netto', 'woocommerce' ) .'</th>
<td data-title=" '. __( 'Razem netto', 'woocommerce' ) .' ">'
. wc_price( $discount_total - $woocommerce->cart->discount_cart ) .'</td>
</tr>';
}
```

}